# Issues with dragging and dropping jQuery UI draggable element from one list and put it into an other

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-droppable

I am using `jQuery UI` and can create an simple drag 'n drop list.
But now, I want to drop the element into an other list. jQuery always thinks the item has been droppen on the false place and slides it back into the origin list.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I think the solution is found here: 
http://ui.jquery.com/demos/sortable/#connect-lists

and its done something like this:

```
$(function() {
        $("#sortable1, #sortable2").sortable({
            connectWith: ['.connectedSortable']
        });
    });
```

Comment: Is there a way to use this for Bootstrap 3?

Comment: Just include the jQuery and jQuery UI libraries, and the code should work regardless of Bootstrap or not